# Linux: Find a List of Files in a Dictionary recursively

Tags: linux, list, shell, recursion, find

I have a Textfile with one Filename per row:

```
Interpret 1 - Song 1.mp3
Interpret 2 - Song 2.mp3
...
```

(About 200 Filenames)

Now I want to search a Folder recursivly for this Filenames to get the full path for each Filename in Filenames.txt.
How to do this? :)

(Purpose: Copied files to my MP3-Player but some of them are broken and i want to recopy them all without spending hours of researching them out of my music folder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way may be the following:

```
cat orig_filenames.txt | while read file ; do find /dest/directory -name "$file" ; done > output_file_with_paths
```

Answer (score 3):

Much faster way is run the find command only once and use fgrep.

```
find . -type f -print0 | fgrep -zFf ./file_with_filenames.txt | xargs -0 -J % cp % /path/to/destdir
```

Comment: although my xargs didn't like `-J` option. For the pipe to xargs, I used:

    xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" /path/to/destdir
    foo
    foo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while read loop along with `find`:

**filecopy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        find . -iname "$line" -exec cp '{}' /where/to/put/your/files \;
done < list_of_files.txt
```

Where `list_of_files.txt` is the list of files line by line, and `/where/to/put/your/files` is the location you want to copy to. You can just run it like so in the directory:

```
$ bash filecopy.sh
```

Comment: I think the first "." on the find doesn't have to be there.

Comment: @Diego I always specify the pathname because some versions of `find` don't assume that a lack of a pathname means the current directory http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_HTML/MAN/MAN1/0505____.HTM . In the case of GNU find, it assumes for you though, so no it's not required here, just a habit I like to keep.

Comment: thanks too but i prefer the one-line-no-extra-scrip-soloution from Diego Sevilla

Comment: @Reini That's fine. I tend to break out shell script one liners because people who find answers may have difficulty if everything is on one line. Good/bad habit to have sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @jm666 answer, but the `-J` option doesn't work for my flavor of xargs, so i chaned it to:

```
find . -type f -print0 | fgrep -zFf ./file_with_filenames.txt | xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" /path/to/destdir/
```