# Copy list of files from one location to another in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm attempting to copy a partial list of files on a drive to a location on another drive. The list of files  to copy is in a text file that I've attempted to supply to a bash script as well as some cp and xargs commands but to no avail. Below is the bash attempt.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    find . -iname "$line" -exec cp '{}' /my/destination/drive \;
done < file_list.txt
```

The text file reads as filenames with no extensions, like below

```
my-file001
my-file002
my-file003
```

I've also tried xargs and pax with the below attempts, also to no avail.

```
cat file_list.txt | xargs cp -t /my/destination/drive
```

and

```
find . -type f -exec pax -rws'|.*/||' < file_list.txt /my/destination/drive/ '{}' \;
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179726/linux-find-a-list-of-files-in-a-dictionary-recursively) came close but not quite. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the real filenames have extensions? Or are they identical to the names in the file_list.txt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [rsync : Read input from a file and sync accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766284/rsync-read-input-from-a-file-and-sync-accordingly)

Answer (score 11):

This will just do the trick for you:

```
 cat file_list.txt | xargs -I {} cp {} /destination/dir/path
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit which each part is used for?

Comment: @Fosna
cat FILENAME : prints the file. In our case it is a list of paths.
xargs : accepts as an argument what was inputted.
-I : defines a placeholder symbol(s).
cp {} : using the input and placing it into the placeholder, run cp on it onto the dest path